# How to use Web Workers into a Module build with Requirejs?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, web-worker

I have a well working app writing with Requirejs and Backbonejs, but it's really slowing sometimes... For example when it comes to make some arithmetic work! I tried to use a Web Worker to do this arithmetic work like this :

**My Module(traffic.js) :**

```
define(["jquery", "use!underscore", "use!backbone", "namespace" ],
  function ($, _, Backbone, globals) {
    .....  
    var worker = new Worker("arithmetic.js");
    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
         console.log(e.data);
    }, false);

    worker.postMessage(globals.data); // Send data to our worker.
  });
```

**arithmetic.js :**

```
define(["use!underscore", "use!backbone" ],
  function ($, _) { 
      //Here die Operations
 });
```

But i have the Error **define is not defined!!**

I tried it like [this](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/tests/workers.js) too but no success!!

How to use Web Worker into requirejs or with backbonejs??

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use requireJS from web workers: see the [API docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#webworker) for more info.

The only requirement is to load requireJS at the start of the web worker with `importScripts(…)`. Once that is loaded, you can use `define` and use requireJS like normal.

The key part for me when I was getting it to work was to make sure that you are also loading the same bootstrap configuration (e.g. `config.js` or `main.js`) in the web worker that you are using in the rest of your app. This is what the doc is talking about when it says:

> You will likely need to set the baseUrl configuration option to make sure require() can find the scripts to load.

Another thing is that you can load the worker from your `traffic.js` file with a module ID (instead of hardcoding the script path) utilizing [this requireJS plugin](https://github.com/chadly/RequireJS-Web-Workers).

Comment: I'm able to get the web worker to load and start, but it won't respond to `postMessage()` if the `addEventListener()` is done within the `require(function{})` block. My worker event listener needs to call various requirejs modules. The example in the API docs you mentioned, namely https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/tests/workers.js ,  does not set any `onmessage` listener. Any ideas?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Alternatively, you could set the `onmessage` event handler directly (though addEventListener is always encouraged by JavaScript ninjas). (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/). **If you use requireJS plugin for web workers, use onmessage  syntax,** otherwhise if native worker is not available, the polyfill fake-worker.js included with the plugin will not work.

Comment: @puro_nervio I was able to get it to work finally. A working example I found had the worker do a `postMessage()` to reply to the main thread before it did an `addEventListener()`. I'm thinking my problem was that the thread wasn't ready when my main thread was giving it work to do. The requirejs of several modules takes some time, so the `addEventListener` wasn't executed before the main thread did its `postMessage()` to tell it to start doing something. In other words, the main thread has to synchronize with it first.

Comment: Here's a [diagram of what was happening](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/svg/XP6nJiD038RtUmeh2yb0sAEg6n83dLg90HYkTrPZcbo2p-aHdXudeIgL42oMp_PlVRyl7YdqbcqBKSO6DJ8v6Th628c-jsDmDNU1FYaS897KO27X7bB7HsIZMY57lGq2sSPIW5tDQ7q6Da9xtLRPqwogNiAIp5F9E5K8QjB2xHeIL10mvOK9dLQP3hLKmFW-46F-d9LbcRrgAARnZtbyvR5PzrsK3SPe3vXd3yXu4s7i1fvH9r6nkflcVgmrkveKSn61fetk0BD7PuU8tnwNklLw09DZxCiporii30OFqxu5lLKMw_tz2OCyKXGCoFcCcixjAyeeUX_qMN5n_h-Bl_WP7T89_IyMfbyPBxnV.svg).