# RequireJS in web worker

Tags: javascript, requirejs, web-worker

I am trying to use RequireJS inside a web worker. The problem is that I keep getting the following error when using it. `Uncaught Error: importScripts failed for underscore at ./lib/underscore.js`

I have tested my configuration options, and they only cause this error when importing Underscore. Here they are:

```
{
    baseUrl: './',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore'
    },
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        }
    }
}
```

I can add more info if necessary. The source for this project is on GitHub at https://github.com/isaach1000/canvas.

**UPDATE:** Still no luck on fixing RequireJS, but I fixed my issue using a Grunt task. Here is the configuration:

```
requirejs: {
    worker: {
            options: {
                baseUrl: 'js',
                name: 'task',
                out: 'build/task.js',
                paths: {
                    jquery: 'lib/jquery',
                    underscore: 'lib/underscore'
                },
                shim: {
                    underscore: {
                        exports: '_'
                    }
                },
                include: ['lib/require.js'],
                optimize: 'none'
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Web workers are pretty locked down; you can’t access the window from them, nor add scripts to the document, nor perform XHR.

Comment: Use browserify instead of require.js

Comment: @minitech I think he wants to load more scripts to the worker.

Comment: @isaach1000 workers have a `importScripts` method that runs synchronously. `importScripts('foo.js', 'bar.js');` - imports `foo.js` and `bar.js` . I don't think `Require` works with that at all, you can write a wrapper for it (shouldn't be hard) or use a tool like browserify or r.js to minify and bundle the scripts together when deploying.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I am currently using the r.js task for Grunt. RequireJS claims they have worker support. The `importScripts` method does me no good because all of my modules are already wrapped in `define` calls.

Comment: @isaach1000 did you remember to call `importScripts` on `require.js` itself inside the worker ? (otherwise, how would it know about require?)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes. Require worked on every module except for Underscore.

Comment: I have the same issue with a different module (my own).

Comment: As @GregEnnis said above, browserify simplifies the whole process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load Nodejs Module into A Web Worker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107521/load-nodejs-module-into-a-web-worker)

Answer (score 5):

Did you load `require` properly into the Worker by using `importScripts`?

```
importScripts('path/to/require.js');

require({ ... });
```

The [test in the require repo](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/tests/workers.js) is a pretty good example, also see Chad's answer in [How to use Web Workers into a Module build with Requirejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244836/how-to-use-web-workers-into-a-module-build-with-requirejs)

Web workers have a [dedicated global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope). The problem was most likely exacerbated by Underscore not using AMD until version 1.6.0 ([February 2014](http://underscorejs.org/#changelog), after you posted the question).

I would highly recommend using `importScripts()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage#Importing_scripts_and_libraries)) as suggested by Benjamin's comment on your original question.

The standard definition can be found at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#importing-scripts-and-libraries

The hassle you get for making sure `require` works for all libs in `webWorkers` across different platforms is not worth the convenience, and performance wise it doesn't take any hit as workers don't affect the performance of your main app.