# RequireJS within ServiceWorker

Tags: requirejs, offline, amd, web-worker, service-worker

What is the right way to use RequireJS for import external libraries within a `ServiceWorker` scope?

In the scope of WebWorkers we can use `importScripts()` [RequireJS in web worker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20863527/1203628).
How would be resolved in the scope of a ServiceWorker where **we can be offline**?.

I think that `ImportScript()` would fail and then need search the libraries into the `Serviceworker` caches, any suggestion??

Thanks a lot.

*PD:I try to create the tag 'service-worker' but I dont have enough reputation ;( (I use web-worker instead).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer at [ServiceWorker / explainer.md](https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/blob/master/explainer.md#importscripts--3rd-party-routers)

> The scripts that have been imported the first time the worker is run
>   will be cached along side it by the browser. The upside is that
>   imported scripts will be downloaded and cached alongside the main
>   ServiceWorker script.

Comment: This is not clear. Can you provide more info about it.

Comment: The scripts imported with ImportScripts are cached by browser along the ServiceWorker script and will be available even on offline mode.

Comment: That's very nice. Thanks